# In PHP is BDD a replacement for TDD or is it here to complete the TDD?

Tags: php, tdd, bdd

I read some articles about both of them and I wonder what is the relationship between these two. Do I really need to take the TDD approach and then add BDD to it?
Or
I can completely ignore TDD and start with BDD.

Your thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion the two overlap in a good way. You would use BDD to create your specification by defining behaviors that are required by your system. You are then free to go ahead and implement the system any old way, but should you do the implementation using TDD you will probably find that there is a one-to-one match between your defined behaviors and your high level tests.

In terms of learning, my suggestion would be to first to go TDD first if you are a coder and BDD first if you are an analyst.